# Generics and Comparator

Tags: java, generics

I am working on `generics` and found that the following code is giving compile time error at `comparing method`.

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Cannot infer type argument(s) for  comparing(Function)
>     - The type A does not define m1(Object) that is applicable here

```
 class A<T> {
    String m1() {
        return null;
    }
}

class B {
    void test() {
        Comparator<A<String>> target = Comparator.comparing(A::m1).thenComparing(A::m1);
    }
}
```

Can some one help me understand this behavior; and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: @GhostCat-- Hahaha...got it . its the language that makes me to look down. Anyways instead of questioning my language please check your answer it's not correct.

Comment: Which answer ;-) ... I hope you already checked out that link I had in there; as that would be really an interesting read for you. Beyond that: please note that I **first** improved the wording in your question before I went on to make sure that you understand why I made that change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you specify the exact generic types at the `comparing` method, the code compiles.

```
Comparator<A<String>> target =
    Comparator.<A<String>, String>comparing(A::m1).thenComparing(A::m1);
```

Answer (score 6):

You should specify type parameter for class A.

```
Comparator<A<String>> target = Comparator.comparing(A<String>::m1).thenComparing(A<String>::m1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.  Haven't gone into JLS but I guess type inference does not work in case of chained method call.  (You can see it works for a simple `Comparator<A<String>> target = Comparator.comparing(A<String>::m1);` )

One quick fix, which is similar to another answer, is help Java do the type inference:

```
Comparator<A<String>> target = Comparator.comparing(A<String>::m1)
                                         .thenComparing(A::m1);
```

Please note doing it at the first method already do the trick.

(Looking forward to see if someone can dig out JLS to see if such inference is supposed to be valid  :P  )

Answer (score 1):

you can nested as

```
 Comparator<A<String>> target1 = Comparator.comparing(A::m1);
 Comparator<A<String>> target2 = target1.thenComparing(A::m1);


 myVarList.sort(target2);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Comparator<A<String>> target = Comparator.comparing(A::m1).thenComparing(A::m1);
> ```

`thenComparing()` expects a `Comparator` object as parameter...

Comment: the `thenComparing` has 3 overloaded methods, two of them take a `Function`